# Setter/Getter not running on second decorator of property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 2 decorators, and when I attach them to a property, only the first one defined executes it's `setter/getter` properties. The inner function itself runs the `Init Decorator 1` and `Init Decorator 2`. What is causing the second decorator to not execute the `setter/getter`?

Here is how I defined my two decorators:

```js
export function Decorator1(): any {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    descriptor = descriptor || {};
    console.log('Init Decorator 1');
    descriptor.get = function (this: any) { console.log('Get Decorator 1'); }
    descriptor.set = function (this: any) { console.log('Set Decorator 1'); }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
export function Decorator2(): any {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    descriptor = descriptor || {};
    console.log('Init Decorator 2');
    descriptor.get = function (this: any) { console.log('Get Decorator 2'); }
    descriptor.set = function (this: any) { console.log('Set Decorator 2'); }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

I am then using the decorators as follows:

```js
export class Test {
  @Decorator1()
  @Decorator2()
  code = '';

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.code = '123', 2000);
  }
}

new Test();
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKYTgJwIZSwRgAoBKALkWzAE9EBvAWAChFFNUoRMlCptMBzduUpUANIgAOmOBNSYoVANKoq5AM5RMMMP3EATVGohaJeTOQAK02fKpojJs8UQBeAHx0mLFgYcxTWK6Ivsb%20ZogAPhF0AL4A3F7eGGBqcAA2qAB0aXD8hADkAJJgMFAo6Fi4gfj5xAnM3iGOWJmCZS6IoJCwCIg8ABYwasLUzrSIyakZ2bkFAOLs5Rg44TV1iDGJPoahAZiZaosdXdDw3FCDwxSjdBMIU1k5efkAyotoy1WYiGtxG1usdicJBNMJYeosTaMKEnHpID6VMwAJhIIxoDAabA4XD6vAEQmuYkk1jkCmUqkQGi0On0O2a5kQVhkpLsdLBmGc7k8DW2fj2QVB-KisQhSXu6UesyKJTKCJWgSRtVFvN2ZlaR064FOvQGQzRYzuKQlM2eC1lFXl30V6yh3mCbL2Bw1sLOuMu%20tuk2NTwKb3Nn3C1r%20tu8WOB9r5ZlFUKhTAgaWwajUiAAKoYyhiWAABOVfIjERI5i1fFEFhoYAxBfL5eqJSaaEDQLAkbl2w5QFMwAC2qDgICghBbXIuQ0yFdQVfwSIAzPlxEiAAxLuqJGNMJhgVAAd1T6ZIcSAA)

```
[LOG]: "Init Decorator 2" 
[LOG]: "Init Decorator 1" 
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 1" 
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 1"
```

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) (specifically, please include your log output as plain text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TypeScript documentation for accessor decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators), when such a decorator returns a value, it replaces the [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description) for the relevant property. And when you [compose decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition), they run bottom-to-top.

Thus, in your example code

```
@Decorator1()
@Decorator2()
code = '';
```

you are first taking the initially undefined property descriptor and replacing it with your `Decorator2` descriptor.  Then you are taking that `Decorator2` descriptor, and modifying it by reassigning its `get` and `set` properties.  Reassigning properties does not preserve the prior property in any way.  The `set()` method containing `"Set Decorator 2"` has been thrown away.   Oops.

---

It's up to you how you want to compose property descriptors.  Presumably you should analyze the `descriptor` value passed in to your decorator and preserve its `get` and `set` properties however you see fit.  For example:

```
return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
  descriptor = descriptor || {};
  const prevGet = descriptor.get;
  const prevSet = descriptor.set;
  console.log('Init Decorator N');
  descriptor.get = function (this: any) {
    console.log('Get Decorator N');
    if (prevGet) prevGet.call(this);
  }
  descriptor.set = function (this: any, v) {
    console.log('Set Decorator N');
    if (prevSet) prevSet.call(this, v);
  }
  return descriptor;
}
```

Here we hold onto the previous values of `get` and `set` and, if they are defined, calling them inside the new `get` and `set` methods.  Note that I'm not worrying about what the previous methods return, and, especially for `get` you probably would.  And it's up to you what order to run them in; here I run the new method logic before the existing one. The important bit here is that you need to explicitly care about the prior descriptor state if you which to preserve it somehow.

Using this approach gives the following results:

```
[LOG]: "Init Decorator 2" // Decorator2 runs first
[LOG]: "Init Decorator 1" // Then Decorator1, 
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 1" // Decorator1's logic runs first 
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 2" // Then Decorator2's logic is run inside of Decorator1's set
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 1" // ditto
[LOG]: "Set Decorator 2" // ditto
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKYTgJwIZSwRgAoBKALkWzAE9EBvAWAChFFNUoRMlCptMBzduUpUANIgAOmOBNSYoVANKoq5AM5RMMMP3EATVGohaJeTOQAK02fKpojJs8UQBeAHx0mLFgYcxTWK6Ivsb+ZogAPhF0AL4A3F7eGGAakmwAbgDi7EEhjlgAdIJQCcxJCKlSqOkAyjkuwYahAZgFauyl3ojJanAANqgFfXD8hADkAJJgMFAo6Fi4gfhjxJ3eeWGFxUGgkLAIiDwAFjBqwtTODGVdPf2Dw6Nj2bNoGDjhy6uJXTDAh1VZdjOAHPAoQbB9PrHU5fa6IGLfRp+FpteqIXbQeDcKAnM4UajidKXREsW4DIYjcZ1F7zd5LFZrH5-QgA6nAjLUsEQqE406E2FdBFwtgcLhI5pmNZCoUY-ZIV4LMwAJhI5xoVxYIs42L4xTV4ikMjkCmUqkQGi0On0TXy5kQViNtnsEqwzncnjhGxauRtm0wkWitHiiJ6sxBaK9ZiKHRDFTDHIjvpR7RKsZSdwpjymMzmb0W-qVDMRka2aNlWMOvLxImJcNJFQzD3Gz1zisChYFXUQv3+GWe7OqoPBkOhak7LCFXRLrRTO3AmIOo-1iCJHq73Qb5KbY2prbpBaLde7zNZQLS1U5w55uP5jPhiK1YunUqYQqYED62DUakQABVDLMGqIAAAgq+5EMQiSgbS+YqpBZQYAYQRjGMpSJKGmAgNAWAkGu3gpr+MAALaoHAIBQIQuHulWYJwEhDRjPgSoAMxjOISoAAxcZ20pMEwYCoAA7n+AEkHEQA)

Comment: Should the previous get/set be called at the beginning or the end of the new get/set?

Comment: It's up to you.  You get to compose the two getters and setters however you see fit.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out out to pass the modified value to the next decorator.

Comment: What modified value?  As far as I can tell I have answered the question as asked. If you have a followup question you might want to post it separately.  Your example code is just logging things, and doing other stuff with the values is out of scope.  I don't mind helping, but comments on an already-answered question isn't a particularly good place to do so.